# Временная сложность алгоритма List.AddRange()

Tags: c#

Из названия понятна суть проблемы. Интересует какова временная сложность алгоритма метода AddRange() списка в C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Если `List<T>` может вместить новые элементы без увеличения `Capacity`, этот метод требует `O(n)` операций, где `n` — количество добавляемых элементов. Если для размещения новых элементов приходится увеличивать емкость, этот метод становится `O(n + m)` операций, где `n` — количество элементов для добавления и `m` — `Count`.

Answer (score 0):

Если при добавлении в список его вместимость `capacity` не нуждается в увелечении, то **O(n)**

В противном случае **O(n + m)**, где n - количество добавленных элементов и m длина списка перед добавлением

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)